# How to call post request

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

```
<http>
    <intercept-url pattern="/shoppingCart" access="hasAnyRole('USER','ADMIN')"/>
    <form-login login-page="/login"
                default-target-url="/shoppingCart"
                authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed"/>
    <logout logout-success-url="/" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID"/>
```

Using above intercept I am able to navigate shoppingcart controller on get method. But it should navigate to shoppingCart controller on post request

Comment: You cannot redirect to POST. You would have to use artificial form post using javascript resulting in probably additional page load (most probably). Why would you want to redirect to page handling post request without any data in rquest is more important question here.

Comment: Try `method="POST"` property of the tag `intercept-url`.